# Configure Java 7 Firefox Plugin on 64-Bit Cent OS

Tags: java, linux, centos, openjdk

I configured Java on my Cent OS 64-bit machine by running the following command

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

But I cannot find the "libnpjp2.so" file as mentioned here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/manual-plugin-install-linux-136395.html

It was supposed to be dead easy! -_-

Answer (score 1):

Download the official JRE Linux x64 RPM from Oracle Java website

http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

The following command is for "Java 7 update 60". Make sure you change the file name of the RPM according to the version you're installing.

Use YUM to install the RPM

```
sudo yum install jre-7u60-linux-x64.rpm
```

Create a symlink to `libnpjp2.so` in Mozilla plugins directory

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/java/default/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. OpenJDK version of java does not come with the plugin. You have to download the RPM from the official Oracle website and then install it.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html

After that you will be able to find the libnpjp2.so file to create a sym link.

I followed this tutorial: http://codyburleson.com/2013/05/06/installing-the-java-plugin-for-64bit-firefox-on-centos-6-4/